# how to get a value using cellEditor in cellEditing datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to get ratedValue to bean.when I add value in cellEditor and click the save button ratedValue get null.

```
      <p:dataTable id="manager" var="item" value="#{employeedaBean.userList}"
                paginator="true" rows="10"
                paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="2,5,10,15" 
                editable="true" editMode="cell" widgetVar="carsTable"
                lazy="true" emptyMessage="No Customers found with given criteria"> 

          <f:facet name="header">  
          Employee 
          </f:facet>  

              <p:column headerText="Rated">  
              <p:cellEditor>  
              <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{item.ratedValue}" /></f:facet>  
              <f:facet name="input">  
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{item.ratedValue}" style="width:100%">  
                    <f:selectItems value="#{employeedaBean.rateValueMany}"/>  
                </p:selectOneMenu>  
              </f:facet>  
              </p:cellEditor>  
              </p:column> 

  </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Please refer to this link http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-datatable-example/

Answer (score 1):

You need to define first an ajax listener : (in your case e.g. below the header part)

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{listener.onEdit}" update=":manager" />
```

then, you need to define : (which you have already - rowEditor or cellEditor)

```
<p:column styleClass="admin-columns-text">
    <p:rowEditor/> or <p:cellEditor/>
</p:column>
```

Then in your listener method you can retrieve the new value like below :

(if you use a `RowEditEvent`)

```
  public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
    User userChanged = (User) event.getObject();
  }
```

(if you use a `CellEditEvent`)

```
  public void onEdit(CellEditEvent event) {
    User userOld = (User) event.getOldValue();
    User userNew = (User) event.getNewValue();
  }
```